# How to convert an adjacency matrix to an adjacency list with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix like:

```
[[  0.,  15.,   0.,   7.,  10.,   0.],
    [ 15.,   0.,   9.,  11.,   0.,   9.],
    [  0.,   9.,   0.,   0.,  12.,   7.],
    [  7.,  11.,   0.,   0.,   8.,  14.],
    [ 10.,   0.,  12.,   8.,   0.,   8.],
    [  0.,   9.,   7.,  14.,   8.,   0.]]
```

How can I convert it to an adjacency list like this one down here?

```
graph = {'1': [{'2':'15'}, {'4':'7'}, {'5':'10'}],
'2': [{'3':'9'}, {'4':'11'}, {'6':'9'}],
'3': [{'5':'12'}, {'6':'7'}],
'4': [{'5':'8'}, {'6':'14'}],
'5': [{'6':'8'}]}
```

?

Comment: Your adjacency matrix looks completely empty. How is that supposed to result in that `graph` data?

Comment: @StefanPochmann There's the original adj. matrix. I had to rollback OP's recent edit. Don't why s/he wiped out the original matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a list of already added edges in a set `edges`. Those edges are stored in a `frozenset`, so already added pairs are not replicated.

---

Then build your graph by *enumerating* the outer list with a starting index of one, then the inner list also with a starting index of one. Zero valued entries are eliminated with the `if` condition on values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

l =[[  0.,  15.,   0.,   7.,  10.,   0.],
    [ 15.,   0.,   9.,  11.,   0.,   9.],
    [  0.,   9.,   0.,   0.,  12.,   7.],
    [  7.,  11.,   0.,   0.,   8.,  14.],
    [ 10.,   0.,  12.,   8.,   0.,   8.],
    [  0.,   9.,   7.,  14.,   8.,   0.]]    

graph = defaultdict(list)
edges = set()

for i, v in enumerate(l, 1):
    for j, u in enumerate(v, 1):
        if u != 0 and frozenset([i, j]) not in edges:
            edges.add(frozenset([i, j]))
            graph[i].append({j: u})

pprint(graph)
# {1: [{2: 15.0}, {4: 7.0}, {5: 10.0}],
#  2: [{3: 9.0}, {4: 11.0}, {6: 9.0}],
#  3: [{5: 12.0}, {6: 7.0}],
#  4: [{5: 8.0}, {6: 14.0}],
#  5: [{6: 8.0}]}
```

Using a `defaultdict` which takes a  `list` as default value will help build the list-valued dictionary on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

Function to convert a matrix into adjacency list:

```
def convert_matrix_to_Adj_list(self,matrix):
    for i in range(0,self.V):
        for j in range(0,self.V):
            if matrix[i][j]:
                # print(i,j)
                self.graph[i].append(j)# add an edge to the graph
                self.graph[j].append(i)# add an edge to the graph
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your answer contains only code. It would be better if you could also add some commentary to explain what it does and how. Can you please [edit] your answer and add it? Thank you!