# Creating Weighted Directed Graph in Python based on User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, graph-theory

I need to create something like this to represent a directed weighted graph based on user input -

```
graph = {
          'a': {'b': 1, 'c':  4},
          'b': {'c':  3, 'd':  2, 'e':  2},
          'c': {},
          'd': {'b':  1, 'c':  5},
          'e': {'d': -2}
        }
```

So far,

```
import pprint

graph = {}
values = {}
v = int(input("Enter number of vertices: "))

print("Enter vertices(keys) : ")
for i in range(v):
    graph.setdefault(input())

edges = {}
for x in graph:
    edges.setdefault(x)

for i in graph:
    graph[i] = edges

print("Enter weights: ")
for i in graph:
    print(i)
    for j in graph[i]:
        var = input()
        graph[i][j] = var

pprint.pprint(graph)
```

I tried but for some reason, it is replacing the previously read weights with last read weights. Any solutions?

Comment: Any attempts so far ?

Comment: You've neither shown your input format nor an attempt, but see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165292/how-to-convert-an-adjacency-matrix-to-an-adjacency-list-with-python/38165410#38165410

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel - you may want to look at https://networkx.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for the library suggestion but I must do it using a dictionary in python. @JonClements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in graph:
    graph[i] = edges
```

You're assigning the same dict (`edges`) to each key of `graph`. Therefore, when you assign a value to any of them, you're assigning that value to *all* of them. It looks like what you actually want is *copies* of `edges`. In this case, since you haven't assigned any mutable values to `edges`, a shallow copy is sufficient:

```
for i in graph:
    graph[i] = edges.copy()
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. However while taking input i.e. taking weights for edges, the order of the keys is random. It will sometimes ask for any vertex & not the one which was inserted first & then second & so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Abhishek dicts have no concept of order. If you need to display items in a particular order, you'll need to sort them yourself. Or you can explore [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an indentation error?

Instead of

```
for i in graph:
    print(i)
for j in graph[i]:
    var = input()
    graph[i][j] = var
```

You maybe intended to write

```
for i in graph:
    print(i)
    for j in graph[i]:
        var = input()
        graph[i][j] = var
```

?